# NG-Grid make full screen

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-grid

We are using angular ng-grid as we require the sorting, etc functionality,

However,  we would like it to be full screen, ie to use the browser scroll if off the screen etc. 
But basically 100% width, and height to match the number of rows.

We are only returning around max 50 items, so its never going to be massive amounts of data to display.

We can't seem to find anything regarding this.

Comment: Is your issue setting the height ? Try specifying this in your css .ngViewport.ng-scope{ height: auto !important; }

Comment: hi, as mentioned by Aardvrak, we have tried to set the height etc. Although this kind of works in a fashion, it still leave the horizontal scroll bar in.. I was hoping that there would be an optio to allow for full screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
.ngViewport.ng-scope{
    height: auto !important;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.ngTopPanel.ng-scope, .ngHeaderContainer{
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Quick Plunker [here](http://run.plnkr.co/DbqlEu0xhPPu6wPU/).

Note: This is not my solution, but a solution mentioned by **[eithankw](https://github.com/eitankw)** as a response on a ng-grid issue [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/80).